# Ayuda python bucle

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Estoy iniciandome en la programación con Python y me he encontrado con un problemilla....
quiero hacer un bucle infinito el cual salga si pulso la opción "s" o si se activa el boton de la raspberry.
Esto es lo que he programado, pero no funciona correctamente, alguna idea?

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)

def prueba()
    boton=12

    gpio.setup(boton, gpio.IN, gpio.PUD_UP)

    salir='n'

    while True:
        print ("para salir puse s: ")
        salir=input()

        if salir =='s':
            return 0
            break
        if gpio.input(boton)==gpio.HIGH:
            return 1
            break

while True:

    if prueba() == 1
        print("Ha pulsado s")
    if prueba() == 0
        print("Ha pulsado boton")
```

Edito: El problema está en el bucle While, ya que tengo la sensación que usando la función input(), se queda "estancado" y no continua con el programa hasta que se introduce un valor por teclado y aunque pulse el botón se queda esperando al teclado.

Comment: Ines, que significa "no funciona correctamente"?, podrías editar la pregunta y agregar más info? por lo pronto, te faltan `:` en los `if` del cuerpo principal y tienes invertidos los valores de retorno según esperas luego.

Comment: Debes decirnos cual es el problemas como comenta Patricio. Una observación, ten en cuenta que input es bloqueante por lo que no va ha comprobar el segundo if a no ser que en cada ciclo el usuario ingrese algo por consola. Para tener en cuenta ambas opciones necesitarás concurrencia, con dos hilos es debería ser suficiente.

Comment: Editado. Gracias! Es cierto lo que dices FJSevilla, pero estoy iniciandome en la programación con python y no tengo muy claro lo que es eso de los hilos que comentas. Voy a buscar información a ver si encuentro algo. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos opciones para lograr la tarea que necesitas, o bien inicias dos programas distintos, separando ambas logicas, uno para el input del gpio y otro para el input de teclado, o si tienes que compartir datos o quieres tenerlos en el mismo script entonces la unica forma de lograr lo que quieres hacer es con Threading ya que como bien te has dado cuenta, el codigo se ejecuta secuencial y la raspberry o escucha el input de usuario o escucha el input del GPIO.

La solucion es tener dos trhead (Hilos) corriendo en background. Uno de ellos escuchara el input de teclado y el otro escuchara el input del gpio.

A continuacion un ejemplo de como se podria solucionar existen varias opciones para crear los Threads.

```
from threading import Thread
import RPI.GPIO as gpio

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)



class UserInput:  
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True

    def terminate(self):  
        self._running = False  

    def run(self):
        while self._running:
            salir=input("Para salir pulse s:")
            if salir == 's':
                print "Saliendo User Input"
                return 0


class GpioInput:  
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True

    def terminate(self):  
        self._running = False  

    def run(self):
        button = 12
        gpio.setup(button, gpio.IN, gpio.PUD_UP)
        while self._running:
            if gpio.input(button) == gpio.HIGH:
                print "Saliendo GPIO"
                return 1


#Creando la Clase
user_input = UserInput()
#Creando el Thread
user_input_thread = Thread(target=user_input.run) 
#Iniciando el Thread
user_input_thread.start()


gpio_input = GpioInput()

gpio_input_thread = Thread(target=gpio_input.run) 

gpio_input_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tecnicamente lo que quieres hacer quedaria así:

```
import RPI.GPIO as gpio

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)

def prueba():
    button = 12
    gpio.setup(button, gpio.IN, gpio.PUD_UP)

    while True:
        salir=input("Para salir pulse s:")
        if salir == 's':
            return 0
        if gpio.input(button) == gpio.HIGH:
            return 1

exits_type = prueba()
if exits_type == 1:
    print("a pulsado el boton")
else:
    print("a pulsado la teclas s")
```

no necesariamente necesitas los dos ciclos while para lograrlo a menos que quieras que nunca salga del programa. pruebalo si no funciona con gusto te puedo ayudar.

nota: los break no son necesarios. el return ocasiona que salga de la función por lo que las líneas luego de un return nunca son ejecutadas.

Un post de utilidad que podrias utilizar:[Physical computing with Raspberry Pi](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/buttons_and_switches/) está en ingles pero podría ser de utilidad.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. He probado y sigue sin funcionar, se queda esperando una respuesta de teclado y aunque pulse el botón no pasa nada, solamente sale del bucle si pulso la tecla 's'.

Comment: en la logica que estableciste simpre preguntara por la entrada: la línea 
salir=input("...") el input detendra la ejecución hasta que alguien ingrese un valor por teclado.